# How to cross compile the program using poco c++ library into ARM-Linux?

Tags: qt, ubuntu-10.04, poco-libraries

I am writing c++ program using poco c++ library and execute in PC environment successfully. But how to cross compile into ARM-Linux .

I am following from the poco GMakeBuildNotes, but I do not know where I made mistakes. Can anybody help me how to cross compile step by step. Here are the steps I am currently following:

1. `./configure --config=ARM-Linux --no-samples --no-tests`
2. `make`
3. cross compile in QT framework

Any suggestions to improve these steps, please?

Answer (score 4):

This post is old and you didn't really stated what's the problem, but still I'll share. I'm getting started with poco for our embedded systems and this is how I compiled it for ARM linux:

If you download and unpack the poco package, you'll find a directory: build/config
Here you can find various preset configs for poco builds. I made a copy of 'ARM-linux' and edited it to suit my needs (these are only the changes):

```
    LINKMODE          ?= STATIC # since we are statically linking poco...
    ...
    TOOL               = arm-none-linux-gnueabi # this is the compiler we use
```

The rest was okay for me!
Then I compile poco like this:

```
    $ ./configure --config=MY_OWN_CONFIG --prefix=/absolute/path/to/target/dir --no-samples --no-tests
    $ make (compiles without a problem for me)
    $ make install
```

after 'make install' (if everything is fine) the compiled libs will be in the directory specified by the '--prefix' option, and they are ready to be linked to your ARM applications.

I hope it helps!

Comment: What version of Poco and what version of STLport are you using? I am not having any luck with Poco 1.5.2 and STLport 5.2.1.